# Ruby - Select item from drop down box automatically

Tags: html, ruby, drop-down-menu, sinatra

I have a hash of `countries` in my `Foo` model:

```
def self.available_countries
    {:au => 'Australia',:dk => 'Denmark',:en =>'England', :fr => 'France', :my => 'Malasyia',:nz => 'New Zealand'}
end
```

Via form below I select a `country` from my `foo` object and  save it:

```
<form action="save_foo" method="post">
<!-- some text boxes -->
<label for="config-country">Country</label>
  <select name="country" id="config_country">
   <% Foo.available_countries.each do |code, country| %>
    <option value="<%= code =%>"><%= country =%></option>
   <% end %>
  </select>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

After saving the form I want to edit the saved record via the edit form:

```
 <form action="edit_foo" method="post">
   <!-- some text boxes -->
    <select id="config_country" name="country">        
          <% Foo.available_countries.each do |code,cont|%>
             <% if @foo.country.eql? code %>
                <option value="<% code %>" selected><%= cont =%></option>
              <% else %>
                 <option value="<% code %>"><%= cont =%></option> 
              <% end %>         
          <% end %>
          </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
```

But now the `country` that was saved could not be selected dynamically.. means it just shows the drop down box as default.

### update

For example I select `Denmark` and save the form, when I try to edit the record `Australia` is selected because its the first element.. but this should be `Denmark`

What could be wrong with my `select box` ? thanks.

Comment: Could you paste whole form?

Comment: When you write that it "could not be selected dynamically", does that mean it's the only available item? Or something else? It'd be best if you pasted the HTML output for the edit form to help make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess You are comparing a symbol with an string here:

```
<% if @foo.country.eql? code %>
```

The first form renders:

```
<option value="au">Australia</option>
```

So You probably save a string.

change `<% if @foo.country.eql? code %>` to `<% if @foo.country.eql? code.to_s %>`